# How to rename all files in a folder removing everything after space character in linux?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, batch-file

Hello I can't use well the regular expressions it's all day I'm searching on Internet. 
I have a folder with many pictures:

- 50912000 Bicchiere.jpg
- 50913714 Sottobottiglia Bernini.jpg

I'm using Mac OS X, but I can also try on a Ubuntu, I would like to make a script for bash to remove all the characters after the first space to have a solution like this:

- 50912000.jpg
- 50913714.jpg

For all the files in the folder.
Any help is appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pure BASH:

```
f='50912000 Bicchiere.jpg'
mv "$f" "${f/ *./.}"
```

Or using `find` fix all the files at once:

```
find . -type f -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; s="${f/_ / }"; mv -- "$f" "${s/ *./.}"' _ '{}' \;
```

Comment: Great! So for all the files in a folder? `FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
  cat $f
done`

Comment: I just edited to provide a find command that will move all the files with space to non-space.

Comment: I've tried but maybe I've written wrong the problem. I need to remove all the string after the first space. I'm getting 50912000Bicchiere.jpg

Comment: 1 moment :D I'm coping some new original files

Comment: Perfect! Can I ask one last thing? Some of the results are like this 339005_.jpg How could I remove this _ for all with a second script?

Comment: Do you want to remove all underscores with blank in file names?

Comment: yes finding *_.jpg to *.jpg because some files have the _ before the space

Comment: So if I just take out `_` before space it will be okay?

Comment: Ah ok, so then I can run the first script!

Comment: You're not using `find`'s `{}` appropriately here. Please consider the following `-exec` statement instead: `-exec bash -c 'f=$1; s="${f/_ / }"; mv -- "$f" "s{f/ *./.}"' _ {} \;`. It'll 100% safe. Otherwise, if you want a surprise: `touch '"; rm -rf *; echo "haha, I erased the whole folder with my stupid file'` :) :) :)

Comment: @anubhava is not working shows that: mv: rename ./99900054 ESPOSITORE ORANGE SPOT.jpg to s{f/ *./.}: No such file or directory

Comment: Please check the edited find command now. @gniourf_gniourf: Many thanks, I used your suggestions.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf and anubava you're my heroes today.

Answer (score 2):

Use sed,

```
sed 's/ .*\./\./g'
```

Notice the space before `.*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of find and a small script.

```
prompt> find . -name "* *" -exec move_it {} \;
mv "./50912000 Bicchiere.jpg" ./50912000
mv "./50913714 Sottobottiglia Bernini.jpg" ./50913714
prompt> cat move_it
#!/bin/sh

dst=`echo $1 | cut -c 1-10`

# remove the echo in the line below to actually rename the file

echo mv '"'$1'"' $dst
```

Answer (score 0):

With [rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

```
rename 's/.*\s+//' *files
```