# Rename and remove every character before _ for multiple files in a folder

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, terminal

[I found this post here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642100/how-to-rename-all-files-in-a-folder-removing-everything-after-space-character-in/19642175#19642175) and it works for removing everything after the space, but I can't reverse engineer it to batch remove an underscore and everything before it within a folder. The terminal line from the post mentioned is

```
find . -type f -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; s="${f/_ / }"; mv -- "$f" "${s/ *./.}"' _ '{}' \;
```

So I need it to be an underscore instead of a space, and I need it to remove before the character and not after. For example. if a file is named:

```
random text _987media.mp4
```

I want it to be named:

```
987media.mp4
```

Comment: You need to give specific examples of how you want the transformation to be.

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bash-internal [parameter pattern substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ f='random text _987media.mp4'
$ echo "${f/*_/}"
987media.mp4
```

to remove everything before the last underscore, underscore included.

To rename all files containing an `_`, in bulk:

```
find . -type f -name "*_*" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; g="${f/*_/}"; mv -- "$f" "$g"' _ '{}' \;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in batch if I CD to a folder with many files in it?

Comment: Batch rename all files that contain `_` by removing the **last** `_` and everything before it *(with Git Bash)*: `for x in *_*; do mv "$x" "${x/*_/}"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your answer to use parameter-expansion for sub-string removal.

```
find . -type f -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; s="${f##*_}"; mv -- "$f" "$s"' _ '{}' \;
```

should just be sufficient. The part `{f##*_}` removes the part of the string up until the last `_` in your file. Refer to this [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) section for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where it was finding the underscore. That is the part that confused me in the post I mentioned.