# How do I rename multiple files before the extension in linux?

Tags: bash, rename

I want to take a group of files with names like 123456_1_2.mpg and turn it into 123456.mpg how can I do this using terminal commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename all files in a folder removing everything after space character in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642100/how-to-rename-all-files-in-a-folder-removing-everything-after-space-character-in)

Answer (score 2):

To loop over all the available files you can use a `for` loop over the file names of the form `??????_?_?.mpg`.

To rename the files you can retain the shortest match of a pattern from the beginning of the string using `${MYVAR%%pattern}` without using any external command.

This said, your code should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob             # do nothing if no matches found
for file in ??????_?_?.mpg; do
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue  # skip if not a regular file
  new_file="${file%%_*}.mpg"  # compose the new file name
  echo mv "$file" "$new_file" # remove echo after testing
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rename 's/_.*/.mpg/' *mpg
```

this will remove everything between the first underscore and the mpg file extension for all files ending in mpg

Comment: Up. Made for the purpose. Will not overwrite files by default (i.e. 123456_1_1.mpg and 123456_1_2.mpg).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep` to strip out everything but the first sequence of numbers. The `--interactive` flag will ask you if you're sure for each move, so you can make sure it's not doing anything you don't expect.

```
for file in *.mpg; do
  mv --interactive "$file" "$(grep -o '^[0-9]\+' <<< "$file")".mpg
done
```

The regex `^[0-9]\+` translates to "any sequence of characters that starts with a number and is followed by zero or more numbers".