# How to rename files removing everything up to the second or third occurence of a character?

Tags: linux, terminal, rename

I have a list of files, in different folders, named like

```
aaaaaa_bb_cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg
```

In some of them, I need to remove everything up to the second _, so they become

```
cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg
```

In others (already in a separate folder), I need to remove everything up to the third _

```
ddddd_ee.jpg
```

How can I do that on Linux terminal?

Comment: This should better be asked over at unix.stackexchange.com. Also add what you already tried.

Comment: @Murphy There are many questions about renaming files right here on stackoverflow. And I have no idea what to try. I know some shell commands, but nothing like that.

Comment: @Murphy Why is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642100/how-to-rename-all-files-in-a-folder-removing-everything-after-space-character-in) fit for stackoverflow, but mine is not?

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate everything up to the second _

```
rename -n s/[^_]*[_][^_]*[_]// *
```

To eliminate everything up to the third _

```
rename -n s/[^_]*[_][^_]*[_][^_]*[_]// *
```

Remove the `-n` to effectively change the filenames, and not just test.